# How can I disable JavaScript in Drupal themes or Drupal itself?

Tags: theming, javascript

How can I disable JavaScript in Drupal themes or globally?

Comment: not sure what is the use case, maybe a more info about what are you trying to achieve is helpful, but you can use hook_js_alter in your theme to remove all included javascript.

hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $javascript = array();
}

Comment: I am not that experienced with web programming would I place the hook in my theme-settings.php file?

Comment: It would go in your template.php.  Also, for better answers you should add a little more detail to your question, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you want it global, you need to create a module to house the hook, otherwise it would be template.php in the specific theme you want it disabled. Most of Drupal requires JS however, and you may find unexpected and weird behaviour depending on your set up.  If you haven't already, disable JS on your browser and run through the site to see how it appears with no JS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in and of itself is not the problem. I'd place more energy into ensuring that your Rich Textareas  (body, comments, etc) and permissions are configured properly. This is one area where people can slip in rouge JavaScript which may be run on other visitor's browsers. Use TLS (Https) by default and use modules that aid in security such as [Security Review](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review), [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) or [Secure Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin) help secure the login process.

There is also tons of great advice and direction on line:

- [10 Simple steps to protect your Drupal site](https://www.stopthehacker.com/2013/06/25/10-simple-steps-to-protect-your-drupal-site/)
- [Configuring text formats (aka input formats) for security](https://www.drupal.org/node/224921)
- [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)